# Trying to understand this code block

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

The following script renders required field background color of Kendo UI combobox control. Although this script works perfectly fine, I find it hard to understand it.

From what I can tell, it starts off with attaching custom property or method 
so called `_input` to Kendo ui combobox object and assign into new variable `_originalFunction` but rather than using this variable it's using this chained object again in the next line which I don't really get and assign returned result into this
from an anonymous function that listens to an event.

In general, I don't really get what is happening inside this function and what the returned value would be.

Can someone please explain in a way I can understand?

```
(function ($) {
    var _originalFunction = kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._input;
    kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._input = function (e) {
        var result = _originalFunction.call(this, e);
        if (this.input) {
            this.input.addClass('required');
        }
        return result;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is happening here is, the `_input` from kendo's `ComboBox` library is enhanced to add a class `required` to the input element.

If you use `_originalFunction` instead of `kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._input` in the assignment line then, you are only changing the value of local variable `_originalFunction`, not the function referred by kendo

```
(function ($) {
    var _originalFunction = kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._input; // store the original function to a variable so that it can be called later
    kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._input = function (e) { // overwrite the _input  function
        var result = _originalFunction.call(this, e); // call the original function to apply default functionality
        if (this.input) { // additional functionality is added here
            this.input.addClass('required');
        }
        return result;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The original method accepts a single parameter, so when we call the original method, we need to use the same context and parameters as it was expecting, that is the reason for the line `_originalFunction.call(this, e)`. But it should be better written as `_originalFunction.apply(this, arguments)` as it is safe against any future change in that method signature

Comment: I get the what is trying to accomplish but I would like to understand the script step by step, what is the function with an event for..etc

Comment: function with an event?

Comment: Thanks, you've enhanced your answer while I was posting my above comment.

Comment: maybe it's nothing to do event, I just didn't understand the use of `e` parameter with that function overwriting _input

Comment: Thanks. Is that a default rule to pass a single parameter with anonymous function? And can you also please explain what `if(this.input)` checks? if `input` is true..doesn't really make sense to me unless I can see what's inside `input`.

Comment: it does not check for `this.input == true` it checks whether `this.input` is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 0):

This is modifying the behavior of Kendo's ComboBox `_input` method. It saves the original value of this function in the variable `_originalFunction`, then gives the function a new definition. The new definition calls the original method, saves its result, adds the `required` class to the input field of the combobox, and then returns that saved result.

Comment: $ is a parameter, the function is a self-executing anonymous function used to create a scope, so that variables are all local and do not pollute the global space, and finally the function is executed with $ set to jQuery, which is one way to pass in jQuery to the local scope.  (Though I've wondered a bit about the necessity of that since jQuery's $ is typically global).

Comment: @Paul In this code it's totally unnecessary, since there are no `$` references in the code. It's just someone's boilerplate.